# Python statsmodels - display regression results by group

Tags: python-3.x, for-loop, statsmodels

I am trying to run linear regressions by group and display results for each material group separately, including the name of the specific material.

My data set has a variable ActYTDVol which I am regressing on UnitPrice. I perform this regression for each Material (=group) separately using statsmodels and for-in.

I am able to run the above regression, however the regression output does not show the name of the Material I am analyzing and I am thus not able to say to which Material the regression output refers to.

Is there a way to display the Material (=group) name next to the regression output?

This is the code I am currently using:

```
import statsmodels.api as sm
from statsmodels.iolib.summary2 import summary_col

for Materials in df.Material.unique():
tempdf = df[df.Material == Materials]
X = sm.add_constant(tempdf['UnitPrice'])
y = tempdf['ACTYTDVol']

model = sm.OLS(y, X)
results = model.fit()

print(results.summary())
```

My current output shows 10 OLS regresssion results tables for each of the 10 Materials that I have. However, it does not say the name of the Material for which the regression was done and I thus cannot know which Material the results refer to.

Many thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can print `Materials` in the loop.

Also, summary has a yname keyword to add the name of the response variable to the summary tables
http://www.statsmodels.org/dev/generated/statsmodels.regression.linear_model.OLSResults.summary.html#statsmodels.regression.linear_model.OLSResults.summary

Comment: Thank you very much! I have tried the below code but am getting an error message "IndentationError: expected an indented block". Do you know what I am doing wrong? I am new to Python and really appreciate your help, thank you!                                                                              for Materials in tempdf:
    print(results.summary())

Comment: 1st line: for Materials in tempdf: 2nd line (after 4 spaces): print(results.summary())

Comment: Now I got it :-) I replaced the print line with "print(results.summary(yname=Materials))" and it works like a charm - thanks a lot for your help!